# WinForms DataGridView font size

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How do I change font size on the DataGridView?

Comment: Note your probably also want to change the row height if you are increasing the font size http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370236/changing-the-row-height-of-a-datagridview

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
    private void UpdateFont()
    {
        //Change cell font
        foreach(DataGridViewColumn c in dgAssets.Columns)
        {
            c.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 8.5F, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do I find out which font is used by default? Say I just want to change the existing font a bit. I get a `NullReferenceException` though.

Comment: You can get a reference to the font used in the DataGridView with DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.Font

Answer (score 81):

In winform datagrid, right click to view its properties. It has a property called DefaultCellStyle. Click the ellipsis on DefaultCellStyle, then it will present Cell Style Builder window which has the option to change the font size.

Its easy.

Comment: Better answer IMHO since it lets you do it at design time.

Answer (score 23):

The straight forward approach:

```
this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 15);
```

Comment: You are THE BEST. THANX

Answer (score 6):

For changing particular single column font size use following statement

`DataGridView.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Verdana", 16, FontStyle.Bold);`

Answer (score 5):

I too experienced same problem in the DataGridView but figured out that the DefaultCell style was inheriting the font of the groupbox (Datagrid is placed in groupbox). So changing the font of the groupbox changed the DefaultCellStyle too.

Regards

Answer (score 5):

I think it's easiest:

First set any Label as you like (Italic, Bold, Size etc.)
  And:

```
yourDataGridView.Font = anyLabel.Font;
```

Answer (score 2):

**1st Step:**
Go to the form where datagridview is added

**2nd step:**
click on the datagridview at the top right side there will be displayed a small button of like play icon or arrow to edit the datagridview.

**3rd step:**
click on that button and select edit columns now click the attributes you want to increase font size.

**4th step:**
on the right side of the property menu the first on the list column named defaultcellstyle click on its property a new window will open to change the font and font size.

Answer (score 2):

In DataGridView, right click properties,
In RowTemplate > DefaultCellStyle change the Font Size,
It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Use the Font-property on the gridview. See MSDN for details and samples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.font.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Go to designer.cs file of the form in which you have the grid view and comment the following line: -
//this.dataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;

if you are using vs 2008 or .net framework 3.5 as it will be by default applied to alternating rows.

Comment: leora questions was about changing font not removing the RowsDefaultCellStyle

Answer (score 0):

```
'   Cell style
 With .DefaultCellStyle
     .BackColor = Color.Black
     .ForeColor = Color.White 
     .Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.0!,
   System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular,
   System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
      .Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
 End With
```