# DataGridView setting row height doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Trying to set RowHeight like this(in code):

```
dgvTruckAvail.RowTemplate.Height = 48;
```

Doesnt' work. I also tried to set Height of every colum I add - doesn't work.

Here is grid properties:

```
this.dgvTruckAvail.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
this.dgvTruckAvail.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
this.dgvTruckAvail.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
    | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
    | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
this.dgvTruckAvail.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
this.dgvTruckAvail.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
this.dgvTruckAvail.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.None;
this.dgvTruckAvail.Columns.AddRange(
    new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] 
    {
        this.colMon,
        this.colTue,
        this.colWED,
        this.colThu,
        this.colFri,
        this.colSat,
        this.colSun});
this.dgvTruckAvail.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
dataGridViewCellStyle8.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
dataGridViewCellStyle8.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
dataGridViewCellStyle8.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
dataGridViewCellStyle8.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
dataGridViewCellStyle8.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
dataGridViewCellStyle8.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
dataGridViewCellStyle8.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.False;
this.dgvTruckAvail.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle8;
this.dgvTruckAvail.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
this.dgvTruckAvail.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 22);
this.dgvTruckAvail.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
this.dgvTruckAvail.Name = "dgvTruckAvail";
this.dgvTruckAvail.ReadOnly = true;
this.dgvTruckAvail.RowHeadersBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.None;
this.dgvTruckAvail.RowTemplate.Height = 48;
this.dgvTruckAvail.RowTemplate.Resizable = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
this.dgvTruckAvail.ShowCellToolTips = false;
this.dgvTruckAvail.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1098, 394);
this.dgvTruckAvail.TabIndex = 0;
```

I'm not binging grid to populate. Rows added manually and cells populated manually. 
Do you have any suggestions on what else I can try to set it? Maybe override Grid itself somehow?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Setting the `Height` property of each **Row** does work.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    row.Height = 80;
}
```

Comment: You correct. See my other question (I found why it didn't work for me) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705640/datagridview-setting-row-height-in-code-and-disable-manual-resize

Comment: You must set the row.Height after the 'DataGridView.Visible' property is set to 'true'.  Write an event handler for the 'DataGridView.VisibleChanged' event, so when 'Visible == true' then set the 'Height' of each row.

Comment: This is more efficient: dg.RowTemplate.Height = 30;

Comment: This works perfect to me! @LucaZiegler that option does not work for me, and I have no idea why! I already gone through all the code and nothing.

Answer (score 14):

Two ideas:

1) Set RowTemplate.Height **before** you bind the DGV

2) Set AutoSizeRowsMode = none

Either or both of these might help.

Answer (score 2):

[`AutoSizeRowsMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autosizerowsmode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property change from none to `AllCells` or to any other value.

Answer (score 1):

Set the **AutoSizeRowsMode** to **AllCells**.