# How do I set the row height of a DataGrid in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, .net-3.5

How do I set the row height in DataGrid? I don't see any property anywhere to achieve that. I am using .NET 3.5 and it's a WinForms application written in C#.

EDITED

Here is the piece of code that assigns the datasouce, you can see that I set the prefered height before that

```
        dgMyGrid.PreferredRowHeight = 64;

        dgMyGrid.DataSource = samples;
```

Comment: I think this would have your answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705640/datagridview-setting-row-height-in-code-and-disable-manual-resize

Comment: I am not using DataGridView. I am using DataGrid.

Comment: When targeting .net 3.5 you should be using a DataGridView control; the DataGrid is only there for backward compatibility. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171628(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: ...should *consider*, perhaps as a work-around if you are not using the master/detail functionality of the DataGrid. No offense intended.

Comment: Yea I know, but unfortunately I am not given the time to re-write the app. This seems to be a common SO thing: "you should be using this instead of that". No offense taken, no worries.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember well there is a property named PreferredRowHeight. Should be set before the databinding.

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't affect the height at all. Seems like a property that doesn't do anything.

Comment: Have you set the PreferredHeight property BEFORE the Datasource ? (see the example in other answer)

Answer (score 0):

Steve's answer works:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGrid1.PreferredRowHeight = 64;
        myTableAdapter.Fill(myDataSet.myTable);
    }
}
```

Will produce a grid with rows at a height of 64. However, this doesn't work:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myTableAdapter.Fill(myDataSet.myTable);
        dataGrid1.PreferredRowHeight = 64; // has no effect because the grid is already drawn
    }
```

Comment: PreferredRowHeight is ignored. The property could be set but it has no effect whether you do the binding before or after.