# When I change the rowtemplate height to 50 it will work for every row exept the last one

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, row

When I change the RowTemplate.Height if will effect every row exept the last one. That one will still be on the original row size 25. I get my rows from a database and here is the code.

```
bool check = false;
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
            com.Connection = _sqlcon;
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.CommandText = "PRO_SHOWDATAGRID";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            dtgvProducten.RowCount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    dtgvProducten.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j];
                    check = true;
                }
            }
            com.Dispose();
            return check;
```

And here is a picture of the data grid view:

[image]

Comment: In the DGV is the last row where you add new data?  When a DGV is set to allow user to add new rows the last row is blank.

Comment: Yes the last row is the last one where i add new data.

Comment: See if any of the answers here helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370236/changing-the-row-height-of-a-datagridview  Sometimes the DGV gets corrupted and deleting and adding a new DGV sometimes helps.