# Default Cell Format Changing Automatically on Datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, fonts, formatting

I have a datagrid that I am trying to format with a specific font.  It is currently set to `Arial 8` on the `ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle, DefaultCellStyle, RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle, RowsDefaultCellStyle`.

I am trying to change the font to `Verdana 8`. But everytime I try to make this change and rebuild my application it reverts back to `Arial 8`.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Some code in involved in your font changing?

Comment: I am changing it in the properties window, so there is no code.

Comment: Is it reverted in the designer or in the started application itself?

Comment: I make the changes in the designer and they appear to take. I then build/run my application and the font has reverted to Arial 8 in the application and then again in the designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it is not keeping the font value in the Properties Window but I fixed it but using the code I found here on stackoverflow

[WinForms DataGridView font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64041/winform-datagridview-font-size)