# How to add font size from the datagrivew column

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview

Please welcome me as am a new member.

I have a datagridview with 7 columns on it. all this are xml file which get loaded to the datagridview. my columns are are follow

Department , Employment , Permanent , contract , Fontsize.

1. I have a xml file called employees which get loaded to my datagridview
2. The user will capture the data from the column cells
3. On Fontsize column. i want the user to enter only two numbers or one for incresing the font size of the current row.
4. if the user enters fontsize of 10, the current cell rows will change the font size(which mean department,employment,permanent and contract will change their font size).
5. the change will only happen on the current cell selected. e.g if you change for columnIndex 1. only column index row will change fontsize.
6. I have do the validations for allowing only numbers, but i want it to take two numbers only.

How can i change my fontsize of column index based on the number entered. I know of font dialog but thats not how i want it to be, i have use it for other client project.

I got this example but it is not how i want it as it got style. i only need fontsize

[WinForms DataGridView font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64041/winforms-datagridview-font-size)

my validations

```
    private void Gridview_Output_CellEndEdit_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            #region this one validate the font number/ restrctions
            int RowIndex = e.RowIndex;
            int columnIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
            {
                bool validation = true;
                if (Gridview_.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value != null && Gridview_.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value.ToString().Trim() != "")
                {
                    string DataToValidate = Gridview_.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value.ToString();
                    foreach (char c in DataToValidate)
                    {
                        if (!char.IsDigit(c))
                        {
                            validation = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (validation == false)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Font must be numbers only", "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                        Gridview_.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value = "";
                    }
                }
            }
```

loading the file

```
               XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(Employee);
```

my gridview column indexes

```
   Gridview_.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(); // for Department
   Gridview_.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(); // for Employment
   Gridview_.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString(); //for Permanent
   Gridview_.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString(); //for Contract
   Gridview_.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString(); //for Fontsize
```

Thanks for your help and i hope my question is constructive enough

Comment: Do you mean you want to change that specific **row**'s font size or that specific **cell**'s font size?

Comment: if you select row 1 and change font size? it must change text size for that specific cell of index 1

Answer (score 0):

The post you linked is the correct way to set it for columns. A couple things I gather from your question:

1. You want to only change selected cells.
2. You want to only change the font size, not anything else.

To change a specific cell font, you would do something like this:

```
dgv.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.Font = newFont;
```

To only set the size of the font, you need to bring over the properties of the previous font with something like this:

```
Font newFont = new Font(oldFont.FontFamily, 43, oldFont.Style, oldFont.Unit);
```

Comment: get me understand something here. which event must i use? I want to be able to write from the cell and i must change that row. can you please also put everything in one code as am still learning and trying to understand

Comment: do you understand me now?